# Replace Alphabet with Number

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

Is it possible I write A and excel count it as 5,and on the same cell I write B and excel count it 4, all the way through to F (where F = 0).

Actually at the end I want to add the numeric values.

Please note, the screen should still show the letters and not the numbers - the only number which should be shown is the total when it's summed.

Comment: If A = 5, B = 4, C = 3? What would G be?

Comment: dear im here to resolve my query not to stuck in another query.

Comment: So, are you saying you only need to be concerned about the values A and B? You also don't say what version of Excel this is?

Comment: im using excel 2010,I just want to say that if some one see my excel sheet then Alphabet appear to him Like A but in backend the cell value will be 5

Comment: Are you only making A 5 and B 4? No other letters are affected?

Comment: I need the similar series from A to F (5 to 0).

Comment: Im making the evaluation sheet ,this is for ranting.

Comment: Right, this is now making sense. A to F only! Great.

Comment: could you help me out in this matter?

Comment: I've made a change to your questin, hopefully it is ok , if not, feel free to roll it back

Comment: Ok I will work on it.I think it will take time for me because I am not   good in excel and excel formulas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do what you want, or at least, get you started.

In Excel 2010 make sure the developer ribbon is shown (Google it as it's well documented). In the developer bar, insert a button from the controls tab [image]

Draw the button on the Excel worksheet. A new window should appear, click 'New'.

Within the Sub and End sub, enter the following code

```
    dim myColumn as string
    myColumn = "A"    'UPDATE this for the column you want to use. In the picture, my content was in Column A, hence I used A

    Dim currentCell As Integer
    Dim totalValue As Integer
    Dim hasValue As Boolean
    hasValue = True
    currentCell = 0

    Do While (hasValue)

        currentCell = currentCell + 1
        If (Range(myColumn  & currentCell).Value = "") Then
            Exit Do
        End If

        Dim cellValue As String
        cellValue = UCase(Range(myColumn  & currentCell).Value) ' I assume you accept a and A (upper and lower case)

        Select Case cellValue
            Case "A"
                totalValue = totalValue + 5
            Case "B"
                totalValue = totalValue + 4
            Case "C"
                totalValue = totalValue + 3
            Case "D"
                totalValue = totalValue + 2
            Case "E"
                totalValue = totalValue + 1
            Case "F" 'we don't actually need F but it was in OP
                totalValue = totalValue + 0
        End Select

    Loop

    Range(myColumn  & currentCell).Value = totalValue
```

Save the project as a macro enabled worksheet

Click the button and see the results.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Dave for taking interest in my query.You did the great job for me,but unfortunately Im unable to use it.

Comment: You need to explain why you can't use it if you want me to help more  :)

Comment: im unable to impliment as you guided.how can I make new button.?How to draw the button on excel sheet.

Comment: I tried but i didnt find new button option

Comment: yes i saw this picture, you mentioned enter the values in sub and End sub I also didnt get this option.

Comment: Yes i added button and selected assign macro

Comment: in assign macro should i click on the record button

Comment: ok..Thank you i will try it seems very helpful for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Excel 2010

Go to Formulas tab, then click "Define Name". A pop up window will show up, for the name enter: A, for the scope, choose what you like, and for the "Refers to:" type: =5

Now on any cell, you can enter the value "=A" and you'll get number 5.

To verify, enter the following value in any cell: =A+2 . The cell value should return 7 (5+2=7). Repeat the procedure for B, C, etc. Remember the names are case sensitive.

Comment: im using excel 2010,I just want to say that if some one see my excel sheet then Alphabet appear to him Like A but in backend the cell value will be 5

Comment: thanks faisal the procedure you wrote here is also helpful for me, but I dont want to show that some can see number, if anyone see my sheet then only alphabet will show, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

A `VLOOKUP` may work here but it will mean you see both the letters and numbers

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!$A$1:$B$6,2)
```

So, in my worksheet 2, I have the following

[image]

and in my workhseet 1 I have

[image]